# python syntax error for : at end of for if statment, no idea why

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am running the following code:

```
with open("tmp/"+filename.stem+".txt", "r") as infile:
        readfile = infile.readlines()
        with open("test/"+filename.stem+".txt", "w") as outfile:
            for i, line in enumerate(readfile) if 'M32' in line:
                if '%' in readfile[i - 1]:
                    outfile.write(readfile[i - 6] + '\n')
                    outfile.write(readfile[i - 3] + '\n')
                    outfile.write(readfile[i - 1] + '\n')
                    print(i)
                    print(line)
                else:
                    outfile.write(readfile[i - 3] + '\n')
```

and getting this error:

```
 for i, line in enumerate(readfile) if 'M32' in line:
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure why, as far as i am awear the : is correctly placeed. Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I now know you can't put a conditional inline with a forloop

Comment: Move that `if` into the body of the `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a filter in this position; it's not a comprehension or generator expression.

```
for i, line in enumerate(readfile):
    if 'M32' not in line:
        continue
    ...
```

You can, however, filter the file iterator with a generator expression:

```
for i, line in enumerate(line for line in readfile if 'M32' in line):
```

Comment: any idea why the write statments would not be producing the epected output when print statments such as `print(readfile[i - 3]`do produced the expected output? the output file is just a reprint of the input it seems.

Comment: Not without knowing what the input looked like or what the expected and observed outputs are. Sounds like a topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine a `for` loop with an `if` statement...

```
with open("tmp/"+filename.stem+".txt", "r") as infile:
        readfile = infile.readlines()
        with open("test/"+filename.stem+".txt", "w") as outfile:
            for i, line in enumerate(readfile):
                if 'M32' in line:
                    if '%' in readfile[i - 1]:
                        outfile.write(readfile[i - 6] + '\n')
                        outfile.write(readfile[i - 3] + '\n')
                        outfile.write(readfile[i - 1] + '\n')
                        print(i)
                        print(line)
                    else:
                        outfile.write(readfile[i - 3] + '\n')
```